# _start label with -nostdlib does not work

Tags: x86

I've been trying to debug one of my code (x86) which reads from standard input and prints whatever content it reads. The code below works when I compile and run with

```
gcc -o file file.s
./file < input > output
```

However, if I make the following changes and compile with gcc -nostdlib -o file file.s the command line argument

```
./file < input > output
```

no longer works. By that I mean nothing will be stored to the output file. Any idea why?

```
.global main -> .global _start
main: -> _start
```

Code:

```
.globl  main

main:
        movl    $1, %edx
        jmp     .L3

.L2:    #write
        movl    $4, %eax
        movl    $1, %ebx
        int     $0x80

.L3:    #read
        movl    $3, %eax
        movl    $0, %ebx
        int     $0x80
        cmpl    $0, %eax
        jne     .L2
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: Also, what does "no longer works" mean? In what way does it not work?